# Panel Close Action destroy all tabs

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

I have two opened tabs like this:

[image]

On bottom there's an iframe (a Panel) but when i close one, the other tabs disappear:

[image]

And got this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined**

The view code:

```
Ext.define('tls.modulos.repservfact.view.Reporte', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
iconCls: 'icon-report',
alias: 'widget.reporte',
closeAction: 'destroy',
name: 'tbReportes',
layout: {
    type: 'border'
},
title: 'Resumen Servicios Facturados',
region: 'north',
flex: 1,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    var storeGenCar = Ext.create('tls.modulos.repservfact.store.Empresa');
    storeGenCar.proxy.extraParams = {IdTipoEmpresa: 'GenCar'};
    storeGenCar.load();

    var storeTransp = Ext.create('tls.modulos.repservfact.store.Empresa');
    storeTransp.proxy.extraParams = {IdTipoEmpresa: 'Transp'};
    storeTransp.load();

    var storeTipoCarga = Ext.create('tls.modulos.repservfact.store.TipoCarga');
    storeTipoCarga.load();

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'column',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    width: 300,
                    padding: 2
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        showToday: true,
                        fieldLabel: 'Fecha Inicial',
                        name: 'FechaInicial',
                        editable: false,
                        allowBlank: false
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        format: 'Y-m-d',
                        showToday: true,
                        fieldLabel: 'Fecha Final',
                        name: 'FechaFinal',
                        editable: false,
                        allowBlank: false
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        store: storeGenCar,
                        name: 'cmbGenCar',
                        fieldLabel: 'Generador de Carga',
                        displayField: 'RazonSocial',
                        valueField: 'IdEmpresa',
                        editable: false,
                        labelWidth: 130
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        store: storeTransp,
                        name: 'cmbTransp',
                        fieldLabel: 'Transportadora',
                        displayField: 'RazonSocial',
                        valueField: 'IdEmpresa',
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'txtPlaca',
                        fieldLabel: 'Placa'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        store: storeTipoCarga,
                        name: 'cmbTipoCarga',
                        fieldLabel: 'Tipo de Carga',
                        displayField: 'ValorParametro',
                        valueField: 'IdValorParametro',
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'txtProducto',
                        fieldLabel: 'Producto'
                    }

                ],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        name: 'btnMostrar',
                        text: 'Ver Reporte',
                        formBind: true
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        name: 'btnExcel',
                        text: 'Exportar a Excel',
                        formBind: true,
                        iconCls: 'icon-xls'
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        name: 'btnPDF',
                        text: 'Exportar a PDF',
                        formBind: true,
                        iconCls: 'icon-pdf'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        name: 'btnBorrar',
                        formBind: true,
                        text: 'Borrar'
                    }

                ]

            },
            // This is the panel for iframe.
                            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'south',
                height: '80%',
                html: '',
                name: 'ifReporte',
                id: 'ifReporte'
            }

        ]
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

If I delete the panel for iframe, works perfectly. But i need it to show a report. 
Some help?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the ID being used on the iframe panel is causing issues since you have two instances that will have the same ID. Are you able to remove the ID and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Never ever use ids in Ext apps. You don't need to because you can use [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to get instances of components

Comment: @Stuart Great! The panel id the same for all views. Just add to the controller (by @Saki) `var iframe = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=ifReporte]');` +1